# Cloning Exact Position of Object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uibutton, position

I'm trying to make a BTD game. For my towers, I've put in a Upgrade button on each GameObject and attached it to the GameObject (The tower) itself. Everytime a new tower is selected, the button for the new tower appears and the button for the previously selected tower disappears. However, my problem is that the button's position changes  everytime I select a new tower by a slight margin (enough to look out of alignment), even though the button's position states the same X, Y, and Z value. I'm currently using this code to tell the position of the button for the GameTower:

```
clone.transform.GetChild(9).GetChild(0).localPosition = new Vector3 (-50, 17, 0).
```

Is there anyway to anchor down the button's position even through cloning (the previous sentence of code isn't working? I'd be happy to expand and share my code if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the position would suddenly change.
But I think you should look at some of these points.

What could happen:

1. The parent of the buttons changes it position.
2. Other code may interfere and change the position without your knowledge.

It's also not correct to use getchild.getchild.localposition.
You should try to make a script that knows its child so you can get the child directly from that script.

something like this

Script on parent

```
public GameObject ButtonsContainer
{
   get
   {
       return buttonsContainer;
   }
}

[SerializeField] private GameObject buttonsContainer;
```

Script that changes the position on awake

```
[SerializeField] private Script parentScript;
[SerializeField] private Vector3 buttonPosition;
void Awake()
{
     parentScript.ButtonsContainer.transform.localPosition = buttonPosition;
}
```

Comment: Ok. I took your suggestions and while I was checking the canvas, I found out that the canvas was causing the problem (it shifted button position relative to the placement of the towers). It also turns out I had to select the option to scale Canvas with Screen Size instead of using Pixel Size. This fixed the position problem. Thanks for advice to look at parent of button.

Comment: Also, can you explain what is the purpose of the Awake method you suggested? Is it an already built-in method in the computer? I've just started Unity C# two weeks ago so I'm new to it.

Comment: @InfinityMax The Awake function is almost identical to the Start function. The only difference between these two functions is the order they trigger.
The Awake function triggers before the start function and it is used alot for initialization such as getting components, filling variables etc.
Hope this explanation helps :)